# KSQL stream not fetching output from topic

Tags: confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have connected kafka to mysql. The topic contains data in AVRO format. Now i want to convert that data into CSV format . For that i am using KSQL stream. When i am creating stream like

```
CREATE STREAM source_avro WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='kafka', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

(If i am running consumer command with same topic it is showing data)
and then giving `select * from source_avro` it is not showing any data.

```
SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest'; (Already done).
```

Following [these](https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/changing-data-serialization-format-avro-csv) steps

Kindly help with the solution on the conversion from AVRO to CSV and whats wrong with the stream created.

Comment: What does `PRINT 'source_avro' FROM BEGINNING` show you? https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/syntax-reference.html#print

Answer (score 0):

> CREATE STREAM source_avro WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='kafka', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

Are you sure the topic into which the MySQL data is being ingested is called `kafka`?

I'd first inspect the topic's data with `PRINT` (https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/syntax-reference.html#print):

```
PRINT 'nameOfYourActualInputTopic' FROM BEGINNING;
```